# Openvpn as nobody fails: Options error: --status fails with '/var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log': Permission denied (errno=13)

Tags: permissions, 22.04, openvpn

Openvpn on Ubuntu 22.04

I can run successfully openvpn as superuser. Now I want to run it as user nobody before making it a service.

```
sudo -u nobody openvpn /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf
```

However I have the following error:

```
sudo -u nobody openvpn /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf                        
Options error: --status fails with '/var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log': Permission denied (errno=13)
Options error: Please correct these errors.
Use --help for more information.
```

I tried to chown openvpn-status.log as nobody.nogroup with 666 rights

```
ls -hal /var/log/openvpn/                                              
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      50 jui 30 12:42 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 root   syslog  3.4K jui 30 12:42 ..
-rw------- 1 root   root      18 jui 30 11:25 ipp.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nogroup  227 jui 30 11:24 openvpn-status.log
```

But I still get the exact same error.
I also tried to change the status file location to /var/log/

```
# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
```

Still the same error.

Any idea how to proceed?